# Managing Multiple Modules in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an Asp.net MVC project that includes three management systems:

```
1.Car rental system
2.Bus ticketing system
3.Home delivery system
```

Each system should have different types of modules and each module deserves an area of its own.How should i manage the project. Should I create three different projects for 
car rental,bus ticketing, home delivery system and create nested area to manage their own modules.I also want to maintain generic repository pattern,unit testing.

Comment: @sajiadraihan, what about the database? Is each one have it's own database?

Comment: I want to maintain one database three systems @Abhilash P A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For asp.net MVC you can create one core MVC project that include (add `reference`) in other project that project contain your Car, Bus and Home `areas`.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Top level architecture]

You can create a main web project for your application with three areas for three modules.

And you can create three class libraries for three different businesses.

So, if you need to change any business logic, you just go to the particular dll and made changes. (ex. go to `MyWebApp.Service.Car` and update and compile the dll and update this dll to your production site to update the business logic for the car rental system)

[image: Main web project]

**Please feel free to ask any doubts on this...**

Comment: But I have diffrent modules(admin,customer etc.) for each bus ticketing,car rental etc. Those modules also deserve different areas.Should I create area inside area.For example: Admin area,Customer area inside BusTicketing Area/CarRental Area/Home Delivery Area

Comment: @sajjadraihan, Sorry, different modules?

Comment: If I had only one project suppose Car Rental, then I should have different areas like Admin,Customers etc. under that project. But if I consider Car Rental as an Area instead of project how should I maintain Admin,Customers etc. under this area

Comment: @sajjadraihan, you can create two different areas for `Car_Customer` and `Car_Admin` just like other areas. And you can treat them like nested by modifying the `routes` of you application.

Comment: @sajjadraihan, Or you can create three web apps and host them on a single server with different virtual directories.

Comment: Ok.I will try any of the last two solutions you gave.thanks